# Checkbox panel to open if sub-checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a set of checkboxes with sub checkboxes

```
 <div id="box-fiter-cat" class="box-filter checkbox checkbox-info">
<h6 class="lead">Categories</h6>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<?php $filteredCategories = $_GET['cat'];foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="heading-
        <?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>" class="panel-heading" role="tab">
        <span class="item">
            <input  
                <?php if(in_array($cat['slug'].'.*',$filteredCategories)){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> id="cat-
                <?php echo $cat['slug'].'.*' ?>" type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="
                <?php echo $cat['slug'].'.*'?>">
                <label for="cat-
                    <?php echo $cat['slug'].'.*' ?>">
                    <?php echo $cat['title'] ?>
                </label>
            </span>
            <a class="pull-right" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-
                <?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-fund">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-
            <?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-
            <?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <?php foreach($cat['childs'] as $childs_cat): ?>
                <li>
                    <span class="item">
                        <input  
                            <?php if(in_array($childs_cat['slug'],$filteredCategories)){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> id="cat-
                            <?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>-
                            <?php echo $childs_cat['slug'] ?>" name="cat[]" value="
                            <?php echo $childs_cat['slug'] ?>" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="cat-
                                <?php echo $cat['slug'] ?>-
                                <?php echo $childs_cat['slug'] ?>">
                                <?php echo $childs_cat['title'] ?>
                            </label>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

On first load it will look like below:

[image]

My question is how do I make sure that when user checks any of the sub checkboxes, the parent panel will stay open? I tried to fiddle around but it resulted in all other panels to open instead only the one that is being checked.

Comment: You want to collapse i.e. close the parent whose child has been checked and leave the rest of the expanded categories ... expanded. is that so?

Comment: @sinhavartika I want the parent to be collapsed/stay open if any of its children are being checked.

Comment: collapsed === "closed" and expanded === "open". Are we on the same page here?

Comment: i think you are looking for something like this . check the url :

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Collapsible-Tree-View-Checkboxes-jQuery-hummingbird/

Comment: @sinhavartika sorry yes I meant open.

Comment: Have you tried using data-target ?? It solves the problem sometime. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/2.0.3/q.js

Comment: @sinhavartika tried this script but didnt work         $(function () {

            if($('.list-group .item input').prop('checked'))
            {
              $(this).closest('.panel .panel-collapse').collapse();
            }
        });

Comment: Hey can you show what you tried.. like a fiddle? Otherwise I would have to make the whole thing for you.

Comment: @sinhavartika that's the script that I tried and it didn't work. I can't make a fiddle because some of it is in php.